# Adding Assigned Values in Spinner NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-spinner

Like in my previous post: [Adding Integers from Different Fragments in a ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20641889/adding-integers-from-different-fragments-in-a-viewpager/20642994#20642994)

But now, I'm trying to assign a value in the spinner of FragA and add it to the int of FragB. Like the previous post, the sum will be on the FragC. Here's my code:

**FragA**

```
public class FragA extends Fragment{ 

    Spinner spinner1;
    String s1; 

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {    

        spinner1 = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner1);     
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {

                s1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                getInt(s1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });     
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fraga, container, false);    
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>  adapter_a = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.spinner1,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter_a);
    }

    public int getInt(String s1) {

        int a = 0;

        if(s1.equals("Hello")) {
            a = 5;
        }
        else if(s1.equals("Hi")) {
            a = 10; 
        }  

        return a;    
    }

}
```

**FragB**

```
public class FragB extends Fragment{

        int b = 20;

        public int getInt() {

            return b;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragb, container, false); 
        }

    }
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager = null; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);    
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));
    }

    public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {  

            public MyAdapter (FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int i) {
                Fragment fragment = null;

                if (i == 0)
                {
                    fragment = new FragA();
                }
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    fragment = new FragB();
                }
                if (i == 2)
                {
                    fragment = new FragC(); 
                }
                return fragment;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 3;
            }   
        }

    public String sum() {

        FragA FragA = new FragA();
        FragB FragB = new FragB();
        return Integer.valueOf(FragA.getInt() + FragB.getInt());
    }

}
```

**FragC**

```
public class FragC extends Fragment{

    Button button;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragc, container, false); 

        textView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        button = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(Click);

        return v;
    }

    OnClickListener Click = new OnClickListener() { 

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            textView.setText(((MainActivity)getActivity()).sum());

        }
    };

}
```

Error at MainActivity getInt() saying "the method getInt() in the type FragA is not applicable for the arguments()"

Comment: what is there on line 18 in FragA.java???

Comment: @Tamanna - String s1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: spinner1 is null or spinner1.getSelectedItem() is null

Comment: you can not access views(Spinner) by instantiating that class. I mean `FragA FragA = new FragA();` does not hold spinner instance. And your views only accessible when your fragment in front otherwise it return null exception

Comment: @SathishKumar - what should I do then?

Comment: me too don't have solution but i'm sure, your above code give NPE.

Comment: You can maintain your spinner value in `MainActivity`

Comment: @SathishKumar - you mean, I'll get the variable a with assigned value via the spinner from FragA to MainActivity?

Comment: yeah, you need to maintain one string vaiable in `MainActivity` and assign FragA spinner value to that `MainActivity` string

Comment: @SathishKumar - can you teach me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Put this line in onCreateView

```
spinner1 = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

Answer (score 0):

->   `spinner1 = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner1);`

replace that with

```
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As `onActivityCreated` method is always called before the `onCreateView` and as you are trying to initialize your `Spinner` its not getting view.

Initialize your `Spinner` in `onCreateView`

**EDITED:**

Try to get your selected item by implementing the `setonItemClickListener` for your `Spinner` as below:

```
    String s1;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        spinner1 = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        spinner1 .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
             s1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                             getInt(s1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fraga, container, false); 

    }
```

Also change yout `getInt()` method as below by passing the parameter of the value which is selected.

```
 public int getInt(String s1) {

        int a = 0;
        if(s1.equals("Hello")) {
            a = 5;
        }
        else if(s1.equals("Hi")) {
            a = 10; 
        }   
        return a;       
    }
```

Comment: Still getting the NPE at "String s1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();"

Comment: I'm getting an error at MainAcitivty "return Integer.toString(FragA.getInt() + FragB.getInt());" it says "the method getInt() in the type FragA is not applicable for the arguments()"

Comment: @user2942600 Try out like this `"return Integer.valueOf(FragA.getInt() + FragB.getInt());"` and if you want to return a `String` then change your return type to `String` like `return String.valueOf(FragA.getInt() + FragB.getInt());`

Comment: Or if you want to return `Integer` only then you need to change the return type of your `sum` method to `String` like `public int sum() {......`

Comment: when I changed it to "return Integer.valueOf(FragA.getInt() + FragB.getInt());" or "return String.valueOf(FragA.getInt() + FragB.getInt());"  it's getting an error at getInt() saying "the method getInt() in the type FragA is not applicable for the arguments()"

Comment: Please update your changes in your question with the logcat error.

Comment: I've now posted the updated version and also, I cannot post the logcat error because I can't run it because of the error that I'm pointing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Use that in `onCreateView`

```
       @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fraga, container, false); 
            spinner1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>  adapter_a = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.spinner1,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
            spinner1.setAdapter(adapter_a);
            return view;
        }
```

**Example :**

```
public class FragA extends Fragment{

        Spinner spinner1;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fraga, container, false); 
            spinner1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>  adapter_a = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.spinner1,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
            spinner1.setAdapter(adapter_a);
            return view;
        }

        public int getInt() {

            int a = 0;

            String s1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if(s1.equals("Hello")) {
                a = 5;
            }
            else if(s1.equals("Hi")) {
                a = 10; 
            }   
            return a;       
        }

        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm still getting the NullPointerException at "String s1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();" ...

Comment: @user2942600 do that setadapter also inside `onCreateView` like my edit.

Comment: @user2942600 I checked it it's working. correctly your giving entries in `onActivityCreated` it's getting late to set the entiers. before setting entries our calling `spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString()` so that null pointer .

Comment: yes. NullPointerException at "String s1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();"

Comment: @user2942600 is that `spinner1` in your `fraga` layout.

Comment: @Tamilan I have one doubt, is it possible to access view of first fragment from third fragment?. He used viewpager and access getInt() of FragA from FrogC. Usually viewpager only maintains current fragment and neighbor fragment to alive. So that  here, FragA view get destroyed. Me too don't have any  solution but i thought this is the problem being here.

Comment: @user2942600 yes you cannot get that values from other class. if you go that activity then you can get that value