# Passing Assigned Value of a Spinner from Fragment to Fragment within Viewpager NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-spinner

I've make it more simple and updated it based on the answers in my previous post: [Adding Assigned Values in Spinner NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20649497/adding-assigned-values-in-spinner-nullpointerexception)

I have a **MainAcitivty** that uses a **ViewPager**. I have 2 Fragments in my MainActivity (FragA and FragB)

In my **FragA** I have a **spinner**. While in **FragB**, I have a **TextView** and a **Button**.

Now what am I trying to do is, when I select "Hello" in my spinner, my int a will have a value of 5. And when I click the Button, 5 will display in the TextView.

Here's my code:

**FragA**

```
public class FragA extends Fragment {

    Spinner spinner1;
    String s1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fraga, container, false); 

        spinner1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);  
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>  adapter_a = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.spinner1,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter_a);

        s1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();

        return view;
    }

    public int getInt() {

        int a = 0;

        if(s1.equals("Hello")) {
            a = 5;
        }

        return a;    
    }

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager = null; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);    
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));
    }

    public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {  

            public MyAdapter (FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int i) {
                Fragment fragment = null;

                if (i == 0)
                {
                    fragment = new FragA();
                }
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    fragment = new FragB();
                }
                return fragment;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 2;
            }   
        }

    public String get() {

        FragA FragA = new FragA();

        return Integer.toString(FragA.getInt());
    }
}
```

**FragB**

```
public class FragB extends Fragment{

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragb, container, false); 

        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(Click);

        return view;
    }

    OnClickListener Click = new OnClickListener() { 

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            textView.setText(((MainActivity)getActivity()).get());          
        }
    };

}
```

By the way, I have no problem passing the value of a from FragA to FragB when this is my code:

```
public int getInt() {

        int a = 5;

        return a;    
    }
```

But, it doesn't involve my spinner and that's not I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **simple way** to communicate between fragments.

In MainActivity, keep static instances of the fragments.

```
public static FragA fragmentA;
public static FragB fragmentB;
```

Now if you want to access FragB from FragA, write something similar:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).fragmentB.setSomething();
```

And Here is a **better/proper way** to communicate between fragments:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: I have no problem communicating with my fragments. My problem is that, the value that I set via the spinner is getting NPE when I'm trying to transfer it.

Comment: which line gives you NPE? Can you upload your complete project somewhere?

Comment: here "s1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();" I don't know where I can upload it.. are you going to do it for me? hehehe

Comment: @user2942600 which one gets NPE? spinner1 or getSelectedItem?

Comment: It's ok now. The string s1 is getting the NPE. I discovered that the problem is in the ViewPager. ViewPager caches only current left and right. If you go beyond that, the fragment will be destroyed that's why I'm getting the NPE.

Comment: And also, I use the hosting activity to set the string of the TextView in FragB