# Initialize a value through if statement NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I'm trying to pass a value from Fragment to Fragment like in my previous post (same problem): [Passing Assigned Value of a Spinner from Fragment to Fragment within Viewpager NullPointerException [Solved]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664419/passing-assigned-value-of-a-spinner-from-fragment-to-fragment-within-viewpager-n/20669587?noredirect=1#20669587)

I have no problem with passing values. But if I added the if statement to assign a value, I'm getting NPE.

**No problem with this code:**

```
public int getInt() {

        int a = 5;

        return a;
    }
```

**I'm getting an error in a saying "The local variable a may not have been initialized" with this code:**

```
public int getInt() {

        int a;
        String s1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if(s1.equals("Hello")) {
           a = 5;  
        }

        return a;
    }
```

**But when I tried to initialized it, I'm getting NPE at "String s1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();":**

```
public int getInt() {

        int a = 0;
        String s1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if(s1.equals("Hello")) {
           a = 5;  
        }

        return a;
    }
```

**This is where I'm getting the error. In my FragA fragment:**

```
public class FragA extends Fragment {

    String s1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fraga, container, false); 

        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);  
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>  adapter_a = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.spinner1,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter_a);

        return view;
    }

    public int getInt() {

        int a = 0;
        s1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if(s1.equals("Hello")) {
            a = 5;
        }

        return a;    
    }

}
```

**fraga xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30sp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/text_a" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

What could be the solution for this?

Comment: check how you initialized spinneer1. post that code here and the stacktrace

Comment: Hopefully you are getting NPE with your spinner. no issue with var a here in your last code.

Comment: either `spinner1` or `spinner1.getSelectedItem()` is null. Please verify. When do you call `getInt()` method?

Comment: where have you initialized your spinner?

Comment: yes it my spinner that's getting a NPE. I already selected "Hello" in my spinner but I always get the NPE.

Comment: @user2942600 post your layout xml also

Comment: @Raghunandan - I've now added it

Comment: @user2942600 where do you call `getInt`. i see nothing that calls getInt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);` Declared and initialized in `onCreateView`. becomes local to onCreateView

use

```
Spinner spinner1; 
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fraga, container, false); 
 spinner1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

Also not sure where you call `getInt`. May be you are trying to call `getInt` before spinner is initialized.

Edit:

For the link in the comment

In fragment

```
public interface OnSpinnerSelectedListener {
    public void onValueSelected(String position);
}
```

Then

```
 OnSpinnerSelectedListener mCallback; // declare as instance variable in framgent
```

Then override onAttach and initialize `mCallback`

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (OnSpinnerSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnSpinnerSelectedListener");
    }
}
```

Then in onCreateView

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Then

```
public class FragA extends Fragment implements OnItemSelectedListener{
```

Now when you select value in spinner

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {  
    String s1= spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    mCallback.onValueSelected(s1);
    }
```

In Activity implement the interface

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSpinnerSelectedListener
```

Then

```
public void onValueSelected(String value)
{
      Log.i("Selected value is", value);
}
```

Once you get the value selected in Activity communicate the same to another fragment.

Reference :

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: I'm still getting the NPE at my spinner. Can we go to my previous post?  I also post it there where I call the getInt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664419/passing-assigned-value-of-a-spinner-from-fragment-to-fragment-within-viewpager-n

Comment: @user2942600 where do you call `getInt`. I see nothing that calls `getInt`

Comment: In my MainActivity...

Comment: @user2942600 all fragment to fragment communication should take place through hosting activity. pls read the docs full http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Yes I did that. Can you check my previous code, link that I posted, where I'm getting the NPE

Comment: @user2942600 i see nothing that uses interface as a callback in your previous link. Pls read the docs and check the edit

Comment: I'm kinda confused. But I'll try it with my previous post. Thank you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43476/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-user2942600)

Answer (score 2):

Null pointer exception has nothing to do with the `int a` variable and it's initialisation. `int` is not a reference type and cannot be null.

It is either `spinner1` that is null (make sure it is initialised correctly) or `spinner1.getSelectedItem()` return null (nothing is selected).

Comment: I've now updated and posted the code for my spinner. Did I initialized it correctly?

Comment: You have to declare `spinner1` variable on the class so that it's available in all its methods.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot leave `local variables` **uninitialized** in your `method`. So, you need to initialize them always. **NPE** is thrown because either of `spinner1` or `spinnner1.getSelectedItem()` is null

Comment: yes it my spinner that's getting a NPE. I already selected "Hello" in my spinner but I always get the NPE.

Comment: Make sure it's properly initialized. The spinner reference where you selected 'Hello' may not be referred by 'spinner1'

Comment: I've now updated and posted the code for my spinner. Did I initialized it correctly?

Comment: Put this line 'Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);' in all methods before you use 'spinner1' reference. You missed this in getInt() method

Answer (score 0):

Please check your spinner1; 
is it initialized?

your code is fine otherwise!

Comment: I've now updated and posted the code for my spinner.

Comment: Declare spinner1 globally.